# adding extra variable inside fetched data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

As you can see below I'm fetching the `idsOfSenders` and with that I'm executing another query to fetch info of that user. So far this works fine.

But as you can see, I also have another variable `$msgDate` and I want to put that in the output of every user. How can I do that?

```
$recieverId = 33;

$query = "SELECT from_msg, chat_date FROM msg WHERE `to_msg` = '$recieverId' ORDER BY `chat_date` DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        $idsOfSenders[] = $row['from_msg'];
        $msgDate[] = $row['chat_date'];
    }

$queryb = "SELECT fullname, username FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN('".implode("','",$idsOfSenders)."')";
$resb = mysqli_query($conn, $queryb);

if($resb->num_rows >0){
    $json=[];
    while(($rowb = $resb->fetch_assoc())) {
        $json[] = $rowb;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

```
case 'gmmn':
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('i'))){

    if (!$conn) {
        return;
    }

    //$recieverId = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST["i"]);
    $recieverId = 33;

        $sqlCheckMsg = "SELECT from_msg, chat_date, fullname, username FROM msgNew LEFT JOIN users_table on users_table.id = msgNew.from_msg WHERE to_msg = ? ORDER BY `chat_date` DESC";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlCheckMsg );
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$recieverId);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($from_msg,$chat_date,$fullname,$username);
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
            $rows=[];
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $rows[] = array('from_msg'=>$from_msg
                                , 'chat_date'=>$chat_date
                                , 'fullname'=>$fullname
                                , 'username'=>$username);
            }
        } else {
            echo "0";
            return;
        }

        echo json_encode($rows);

}
break;
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. Do it properly, **it is not hard to fix**.

Comment: @tadman I just whished that you took 3sec to read the first line of this post.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you know it's unsafe, changing your code to use the safe version is _a few seconds of work_, so if you care about your code enough to ask people on Stackoverflow for help, put in the few seconds of work to make your code not have a giant security exploit. As for how you get more data in: just update `$json` before you `json_encode` and return it? Also, if you're returning JSON, don't return `0`, return `{}`, so that the content will always be a proper object when parsed by whatever's using it.

Comment: It takes a lot more effort and energy to apologize for your sloppy code than to fix it up. This stuff is **extremely important** to get right, so when you half-ass some code and then give a lame apology it reflects badly not only on you, but programmers as a whole. This "I'll fix it later" or "it's just test code!1!" attitude is why there's never a shortage of entries on the [SQL Injection Hall of Fame](https://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/) page. Nip it in the bud now.

Comment: Is this question solved? What's the status of it?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where a `JOIN` comes in handy. What you're doing with two queries can be done in one, and as a plus, there's no need for that horrendous `implode` injection:

```
SELECT from_msg, chat_date, fullname, username
  FROM msg
  LEFT JOIN users on users.id=msg.from_msg
  WHERE to_msg=? ORDER BY `chat_date` DESC
```

This should be *significantly* faster and safer since it doesn't involve a round-trip through PHP before going back to the database.

> Note: Ensure that `msg` is indexed on `from_msg` to make this `JOIN` operation efficient. You can check the query performance with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is what I did need to know. I have updated the post, Can u please check it?

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable, and good job on using a placeholder. That code is safe now, and as a plus, won't cause trouble in the future. Debugging escaping errors is super tedious.

Answer (score 0):

There is no doubt you should use @tadman's answer.  With that said, the main issue you have is that a single user can have sent any number of messages to a receiver.

Say that I am `usera` and I sent messages to receiverId `33` a week ago, yesterday and today.  There are 3 messages with 3 different dates.   You would need to have 3 rows for that user, reflecting the 3 messages.

I don't advise that you use the following method, but it will work, depending on how you look at it, by resolving the fact that a user can have sent more than one msg with an associated chat_date.  This code will store the messages in an array, and add them to the fetched result for each user.  You would still have to deal with the fact that 'chat_date' is an array of dates rather than a single scalar value like the rest of the result set.

```
            $recieverId = 33;

            $query = "SELECT from_msg, chat_date FROM msg WHERE `to_msg` = '$recieverId' ORDER BY `chat_date` DESC";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                    $idsOfSenders[] = $row['from_msg'];
                    //msgDate will be an array of all the dates sent for this member to the other member
                    $msgDate[$row['from_msg']][] = $row['chat_date'];
                }

            $queryb = "SELECT id, fullname, username FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN('".implode("','",$idsOfSenders)."')";
            $resb = mysqli_query($conn, $queryb);

            if($resb->num_rows >0){
                $json=[];
                while(($rowb = $resb->fetch_assoc())) {
                    // Add the array of this user's sent message dates
                    $rowb['msg_date'] = $msgDate[$rowb['id']];
                    // get rid of the users.id column if you don't want it
                    unset($rowb['id']);
                    $json[] = $rowb;
                }
                echo json_encode($json);
            } else {
                echo "0";
            }
```

This does assume that the user's table primary key is named id.  If not, relevant code needs to be changed to reflect the name of the user table primary key which is being stored in from_msg and to_msg of the msg table.

As you should be able to see, this is an ugly hack.  The relational database takes care of this for you.  Again, @tadman's solution is the way to go, but I thought it might help you understand your current problem better, if I showed you how you could make it work, and the things you were missing.

Update: Now that you implemented @tadman's query, I would personally not bind the result, as that is causing you in this situation to use a lot of variables you don't really care about.  This is simpler:

```
                $sqlCheckMsg = "SELECT from_msg, chat_date, fullname, username FROM msgNew LEFT JOIN users_table on users_table.id = msgNew.from_msg WHERE to_msg = ? ORDER BY `chat_date` DESC";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlCheckMsg );
                $stmt->bind_param("i",$recieverId);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $rows = array();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $rows[] = $row;
                }
       
                if (count($rows) > 0) {
                    echo json_encode($rows);
                    return;  
                } else {
                    echo "0";
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: It looks like you addressed the complaints about not using parameterized queries and used tadman's suggestion.  So I would say good job!  Is it working?

Comment: Yes it is working like how I want, It's not that I didn't know how to use parameterized queries, it's just that I didn't know how to make query that I was asking for and with the help/advice I would build it the right way. Thank you.

Comment: See my update, for a suggestion on handling your results in a simpler/cleaner manner.  Otherwise it seems you did well.  You should certainly upvote and accept tadman's answer as well.  If I helped you out at all, then feel free to upvote me or not.